# Importing Mongoose Schemas in my NextJS page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm particularly new to NextJS, and I was wondering if I could ask for a bit of help with an issue that I am having.

I have 2 Mongoose schemas defined and have been using one schema in my page for a while with no issues. However, as soon as I import the 2nd schema, my page refuses to render with the attached error.

It doesn't matter which schema I import, but as soon as a second schema is imported, I get the same error for the second schema.

Here is each schema:

**User.js**

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false });

export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**Album.js**

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const AlbumSchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, { strict: false });

export default mongoose.models.Album || mongoose.model("Album", AlbumSchema);
```

And here is the page in which the error is occurring.

**albums.js**

```js
import Layout from "@/Components/Dashboard/DashLayout";

import AlbumCard from "@/Components/Dashboard/Albums/AlbumCard";
import AlbumSchema from "@/models/Album";
import dbConnect from "@/utils/dcConnect";

export default function DashAlbums({ albums }) {
    return (
        // Page content removed for import
    );
}

// Require authentication
DashAlbums.auth = true;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    dbConnect();
    const albums = await AlbumSchema.find()
    const data = albums.map(album => {
        return { _id: album._id, name: album.name, cover: album.cover }
    });

    return { props: { albums: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) } }
}
```

Please could someone help me figure out where I have gone wrong?

I've tried only exporting the model, but NextJS doesn't like that and I don't have enough knowledge to figure out where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is you cannot import the Mongoose schema code into the client components.

You have to write an API route, write this logic in api handler

```
dbConnect();
const albums = await AlbumSchema.find()
const data = albums.map(album => {
    return { _id: album._id, name: album.name, cover: album.cover }
});
```

then in `getServerSideProps` you make a request to that api path and return the correct result inside `props` object

Comment: I haven't tried that. However, I have since fixed the issue by adding a question mark to the following. 

`export default mongoose.models?.Album || mongoose.model("Album", AlbumSchema);`

I do want to try and use API routes in the future so thank you for your response, I will mark it as the solution. :)